# Set and Update concurrenthashmap from multiple thread

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, concurrenthashmap

I am implementing a Client Lookup Map where i am using ConcurrentHashamp.

```
    private ConcurrentHashMap<String,SignupDTO> map = new <String,SignupDTO> ConcurrentHashMap();*
    public  SignupDTO get(String opcode) 
    {
      return this.map.get(opcode);
    }
    public  void set(String opcode,SignupDTO dto) 
    {
      this.map.put(opcode, dto);
    }
```

Here get and set function called from multiple thread to update and get client information.
**I have another function update() which is called from a specific thread after certain time  and  update the map with updated client information.**

```
public  void update() 
    {
        Connection connection = null;
        Statement stmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;

        try 
        {
            connection = DatabaseManager.getInstance().getConnection();
            stmt = connection.createStatement();    
            String sql= "select * from client";
            rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
            while (rs.next()) 
            {
                SignupDTO row = new SignupDTO();
                ......
                            ..........
                this.map.put(key, row);         
            }

        } 
    }
```

get and set operation on map will be thread safe or not? please help me.

Comment: i mean get and set operation on map will be thread safe or not.

Comment: @nosid i mean get and set operation on map will be thread safe or not.

Comment: @nosid could not understand "However, the individual operations in the method update are visible before the whole method is done."

Comment: Imagine that the map initially contains `"foo"=1` and `"bar"=2`. The method `update` reads `"foo"=3` and `"bar"=4` from the database and performs the updates. Then another thread might read `"foo"=3` and afterwards `"bar"=2`. That's basically the worst thing that can happen.

Comment: @nosid i got your point. how can i avoid this scenario?

Comment: First, you should improve the question: Describe more precisely what you need and what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

As @nosid pointed out, your `update` method will not be thread safe (= it can update only half of map, then someone can read mixture of old/new values, and the your update method will finish updating the other half).

I recommend you put your query result into a Map (not nesseserly concurrent one) and the update with [`putAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#putAll%28java.util.Map%29) method from your ConcurrentHashMap, which is thread-safe (or at least [official documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) caims so).